# Where can I find a list of Default VB Buttons?

Tags: vba

In a recent question about using Excel a couple of the suggested answers used the vbOkCancel and vbYesNo codes to make a super easy message box. This was perfect, and exactly what I was looking for, and it got me thinking, surely there are more "preformatted buttons" in VB. However my Google-Fu has produced little in the way of results, probably mainly because I don't know the right terminology for these. Is there a list of the VB Buttons somewhere?

Comment: They're the same values as those defined for the [Win32 `MessageBox` API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505.aspx): `MB_OK`, `MB_OKCANCEL`, `MB_RETRYCANCEL`, `MB_YESNO`, `MB_YESNOCANCEL`, `MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE`, and `MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE`. Note that Abort/Retry/Ignore has been deprecated in favor of CancelTryContinue, available on W2K and later.

Comment: Type `MsgBox "hello",` into the VBA editor. When you press `,` you get a dropdown list of all the buttons you can use with MsgBox. Or put your cursor in the word `MsgBox` and press F1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link shows you a list of these buttons along with their constants names

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf31e8be%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

I will show the relevant list here just in case this link is down for whatever reason:

> ```
> vbOKOnly            OK button only (default).
>
> vbOKCancel          OK and Cancel buttons.
>
> vbAbortRetryIgnore  Abort, Retry, and Ignore buttons.
>
> vbYesNoCancel       Yes, No, and Cancel buttons.
>
> vbYesNo             Yes and No buttons.
>
> vbRetryCancel       Retry and Cancel buttons.
> ```

It is generally a good idea to use MSDN for your VB needs as it is a Microsoft product. I use it on a daily basis for looking C# classes and methods.

Answer (score 2):

[This list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.msgboxstyle.aspx) gives you all of the standard message box styles, along with their VB button equivalents.